# Spark dataframe ambiguous column error when there is no JOIN

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark dynamic frame, `dyf`, with the schema (only 2 columns for simplicity):

```
root
|--name : string
|--profile.info : string
```

The following query:

```
df = dyf.toDF()
df.select("`profile.info`")
```

returns the error:

```
AnalysisException: Reference '`profile.info`' is ambiguous, could be: profile.info, profile.info.
```

Ambiguous column errors are nothing new, but they are always about a join. But I am simply doing a select here. What could be the problem ?

Again, I have looked at all possible variation of this question but they (understandably) all stem from a JOIN statement somewhere.

**EDIT:**
After doing `df.explain()` I get:

```
== Physical Plan == 
* (1) Scan ExistingRDD [name#0, profile.info#1]
```

and the spark version is `3.3`

**EDIT:**
I figured out the issue - it was due to a (possible) bug in `create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog` method of `GlueContext` where it was creating duplicate column names when the source column (in a glue data catalog table) has at least two dots in the name. In particular, a source column `a.b.c` caused the resulting dynamic frame (`dyf`) to have two columns - `a.b.c` and `a.b.C` - for whatever reason.

Either way the issue is not with the select statement, but with `create_dynamic_frame.`

Comment: Why do you need to run the `toDF()` method?

Comment: Can you do a df.explain() just before your select() and post the result here please ?

Comment: also add the spark version please

Comment: @ARCrow the notebook script is generated by what I put in the Visual ETL interface where I design the ETL. Currently, it's just a glue table as a source, SQL to transform and a S3 bucket as target. The problem I am having is with the SQL part that gets generated by AWS.